# Android how to call the method 25 times per second?

Tags: android, framebuffer

I am developing an application which is used to call take the screen shots from devices and saving in external sdcard.  i am able to take the screen shots only 5 per second .. if i exceeds the no of screen shots the mobile ui gets hangs.. i am unable to get the sequence. so please advice me.

First i am taking the frame-buffer as the raw file then converting this as the images. 
i need to take to both processes concurrently and also should get atleast 25 frames per second. how should i call the method ?

Comment: Are you running your code in main thread?

Comment: There is no fix time for running a method.. Its depends on how resources are available and when its completing.. In your case.. The whole process to run a single method is taking much time. So whenever its not completing you can force for running second time. May be possible the resources you need (framebuffer) is busy by other process. Also converting raw data to your desired image also take some image processing time..

Comment: May be possible if you are running 25 different thread at a time for running method but i think all gets the Resource busy as your framebuffer read by different threads..